# JSON file in Index.html

Tags: html, json

I am trying to show in my index.html the contents of a JSON file I have created using an onload call in the body to a function located in the script.js file. I have finished the function and no data is displayed, and there is an error message in the console that displays "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
at XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest.onload (script.js:14)"

The error appears if I leave the line that says "ourRequest.send()". If I comment this line, the error won't show up, but it will still not show the data.

This is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Showing comments stored in json</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body onload="commentLoad()">

    <article>
        <div class="container"></div>
    </article>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the script.js file:

```
function commentLoad(){
    

    var textContainer = document.getElementById("container");
    

    var ourRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    ourRequest.open('GET','comments.json');
    ourRequest.onload = function(){
        var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        var userCommentData = "";
        
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            userCommentData += "<p> User Name: " + ourData[i].name + " Score: " + ourData[i].score + " <p> User Comment: " + ourData[i].comment + "</p> </p>"; 
        }
        textContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',userCommentData);
        
       
    }
    ourRequest.send();
 
}
```

Finally, this is my comments.json file:

```
[{
        "name": "John",
        "score": "5",
        "comment": "Best thing I have ever tried"
    },
    {
        "nombre": "Tom",
        "nota": "4",
        "comentario": "Very good"
    }

]
```

Comment: `for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)` - you probably intended to type `for(i=0;i<ourData.length;i++)`

Comment: Thanks, just changed it but now the console loads the following error: 


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest.onload (script.js:17)

Comment: `<div class='container'>` won't be located with a call to document.getElementById('container')` Since the attempt to set `container` to point at an HTML element fails, so does the call to `insertAdjacentHTML`